# Swiftui using UITextVIew for hyperlink but can't change text color

Tags: swiftui, uitextview, textcolor

I am trying to use UITextView in swiftui to display a text which contains hyperlinks inside. The text and the links should be with same color except the links are underlined.

I tried to implement UITextView, but I only managed to change the link foreground color.
I added textView.textColor = xxx but it didn't work. Only my links' color are changed.

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
    
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.font = font
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.textColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5)
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        textView.frame = textView.frame.integral
    
        return textView
    }


   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    
        for (hyperLink, urlString) in hyperLinks {
            let linkRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: hyperLink)
            let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedOriginalText.length)
            attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: urlString, range: linkRange)
            attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: fullRange)
        }
    
        uiView.linkTextAttributes = [
            .underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5)
        ]
    
        uiView.attributedText = attributedOriginalText
    
        // COMPUTE HEIGHT FOR CONTENT
        let width = uiView.frame.size.width
        let newSize = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dynamicHeight = newSize.height
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you apply attributedText after textColor, it has a priority, so change color via attributes.

Comment: @Asperi , Do you have any idea how can I find the range of the text excluded the link?

Comment: Why? You said: "The text and the links should be with same color", so set it for full range, and then add underline style only for links.

Comment: @Asperi I tried adding the foreground color  attribute using the full range. But the link is in blue color. So then I add the link text attributes like I did above, and it broke the text color. The whole text become white and pixelated and only the underline is applied.

Comment: @Asperi It turns out if the color in the link text attributes is same as the attribute above, it will break the text. I used a similar color as a workaround like 254, 254, 254. If you know why same color doesn't work, please tell me, thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I meant. Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

*Red color used for better visibility

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    for (urlString, hyperLink) in links {
        let linkRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: hyperLink)
        attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(.link, value: urlString, range: linkRange)
    }

    let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedOriginalText.length)
    attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: fullRange)

    uiView.attributedText = attributedOriginalText
    uiView.linkTextAttributes = [
        .underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is what I did, except I use UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.5) on both places. But the text become broken. I then use 244 244 244 for the link to fix the issue.

Comment: What a great answer, `linkTextAttributes` is indeed the secret.  There is I believe some soft bugs / bugs if you try to change them "manually" at add attribute.  Thanks good one.